# Correct way to integrate current navigation

Tags: 2013, master-page, publishing-site, current-navigation

What is the correct way to integrate current navigation in a publishing site?

1. Make one master page which contain current navigation. Hide current navigation on home page using jquery.
2. Make two different master pages; one for home page without current navigation and one for inner pages which will have current navigation.

Is there any other way?